# AWS Lambda: Find Resources that are not Tagged

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am creating a config rule which uses a custom lambda function that checks if a configuration item has tags in it. I want the rule to run for all resources but I am finding that some resources such as IAM groups, roles, users, etc. cannot be tagged. Nevertheless, the configuration items for these resources have a tags attribute which makes it difficult to distinguish between resources that can be tagged but are not and resources that cannot be tagged at all.

Does anyone have any ideas on how I can filter out the resources which cannot be tagged?

I realize I could just identify what resources currently do not support tags by looking at the documentation and statically ignoring these types in the lambda but I would like a more dynamic solution which doesn't require me to update my lambda every time a new resource is discovered/released which does not support tags.

Answer (score -1):

A little late to the party perhaps - better late than never! ;-)

##### Resources you can use with AWS Resource Groups and Tag Editor

> You can use the AWS Management Console or the AWS CLI to create
> resource groups and then interact with the member resources through
> those groups. You can add tags to many AWS resources and then use
> those tags to manage group membership. This topic describes the AWS
> resources that you can include in resource groups by using AWS
> Resource Groups, and the AWS resources that you can tag by using Tag
> Editor...
>
> > **Note:** Adding tags to a AWS CloudFormation stack causes an update of the stack.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ARG/latest/userguide/supported-resources.html

---

##### AWS Resource Groups Tagging API Reference

> AWS supports tagging on all core infrastructure resources that incur
> charges. Most other AWS resources also support tagging. Some resources
> support tagging only through that service's native tagging operations,
> and don't yet support this API. See the documentation for an
> individual service for information about that service's native tagging
> operations…
>
> You can use the Resource Groups Tagging API operations to complete the
> following tasks:
>
> - Tag and untag supported resources located in the specified Region for the AWS account.
> - Use tag-based filters to search for resources located in the specified Region for the AWS account.
> - List all existing tag keys in the specified Region for the AWS account.
> - List all existing values for the specified key in the specified Region for the AWS account.
>
> To use Resource Groups Tagging API operations, you must add the
> following permissions to your IAM policy:
>
> - `tag:GetResources`
> - `tag:TagResources`
> - `tag:UntagResources`
> - `tag:GetTagKeys`
> - `tag:GetTagValues`
>
> You'll also need permissions to access the resources of individual
> services so that you can tag and untag those resources.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/resourcegroupstagging/latest/APIReference/overview.html

---

##### Services that support the Resource Groups Tagging API

> You can use the Resource Groups Tagging API to tag resources for the
> AWS services listed at the URL linked below.[3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/resourcegroupstagging/latest/APIReference/supported-services.html)
>
> > **Note:** The list includes only those AWS services that work with the
> > Resource Groups Tagging API.
> >
> > If an AWS service isn't listed, you might still be able to tag that
> > service's resources by using the service's native tagging operations
> > instead of using the Resource Groups Tagging API operations. See the
> > documentation for an individual service for information about that
> > service's native tagging operations.
> >
> > This lets you tag resources by using the AWS CLI version of the
> > service's operation. For example, you could tag an IAM user by using a
> > command similar to the following example:
> >
> > ```
> > $ aws iam tag-user --user-name kristy --tags Key=CostCenter,Value=1234
> > ```

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/resourcegroupstagging/latest/APIReference/supported-services.html